# Create bootloader on an SD card

Tags: linux, boot-loader, lubuntu

I am new to linux, I use Lubuntu,       I installed the bootloader on an USB drive, I connect the USB in order to load the OS  which was installed on a HD partition,

I need to use the USB for other stuff, so I need to format it, and I have a clean unused SD card,       could someone tell me how to put the bootloader on the SD card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#sudo fdisk -l
```

find you sdcard device

```
#sudo grub-install /dev/<insert sd drive name here>
```